# JQuery click code not running on first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was pleasantly surprised with many finds to my problems similar to my own, but after about 15 of them I couldn't find someone with the same problem I'm having.

The problem I have is that my click event code is not executing on the first click. I can see within the console.log() or alert that the event is firing, however, the code (other than the alert/log) is not executing. I am not seeing any errors in the console.

There are 3 li buttons in this example and all 3 of them behave the same way - they all ignore the first first click only showing the alert/log.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search-multi-property-type").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        var prependText = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> ";
        var value = $(this).data("id");

        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
            //tasks to the button
            $(this).css("background-color", "#5cb85c");
            $(this).css("color", "white");
            $(this).prepend(prependText);

            //tasks to the input
            $("#lease-type-input").val(function(i,val) {
                 return val + (!val ? '' : ', ') + value;
            });
            alert($("#lease-type-input").val());
        }

        //if it is active, make it inactive
        if($(this).hasClass("active")){
            //tasks to the button
            $(this).css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
            $(this).css("color", "black");
            $(this).find(".glyphicon").remove();

            //tasks to the input
            $("#lease-type-input").val($("#lease-type-input").val().replace(value + ", ", ""));
            $("#lease-type-input").val($("#lease-type-input").val().replace(", " + value, ""));
            $("#lease-type-input").val($("#lease-type-input").val().replace(value, ""));
            alert($("#lease-type-input").val());
        }
    });
});

<li class="dropdown-label">Property Type<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span></li>
                        <ul class="search-multi-row">
                        <input id="lease-type-input" name="lease_type" type="hidden">

                            <li data-id="APT" class="search-multi search-multi-property-type">Apartment</li>

                            <li data-id="SUB" class="search-multi search-multi-property-type">Sublease</li>

                            <li data-id="HOU" class="search-multi search-multi-property-type">House</li>

                        </ul>


      </li>
```

Comment: Well for starters, your HTML is invalid. A `<ul>` can't have another `<ul>` as a child (or anything other than a `<li>` for that matter).

Comment: Apart from that, I’d say it’s probably quite a sure bet to say that the click hander _is_ executed, but does not do what you want it to do because of the conditions inside it not being true. (_That_ you could’ve found out yourself btw. by doing some really simple debugging …)

Comment: People dont be harsh, sometimes everyone stucks at simple things :) looks like he is new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `$(this).toggleClass("active");`

you should place it at the bottom of the function

Please check working example at

http://jsfiddle.net/Am6Sm/

Comment: ah, duh yeah that makes perfect sense. Thanks.